# How can I sum the series $e^{-2}\frac{(3)^n}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left ( \frac{1}{2}\right )^k\frac{1}{(k-n)!}$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, sequences-and-series, summation, closed-form

How can I sum the following series?

$$e^{-2}\frac{(3)^n}{n!}\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\left ( \frac{1}{2}\right )^k\frac{1}{(k-n)!}$$

I think I can make this sum in the form of exponential expansion but not able to think how. Any initial hint would be great. Thanks in advance.

Comment: that does not makes sense to start the sum at $x=0$

Comment: Are $x$ and $y$ both integers? If so, what is $(x-y)!$ for $y>x$?

Comment: @GuyFsone if $y> 0$ then $\frac1{(-y)!}=0$ because $|(-y)!|=\infty$

Comment: @Masacroso Why is $|(-y)!|=\infty$, what are you using to define the negative factorial?  See also [this](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10124/the-factorial-of-1-2-3).

Comment: @Masacroso how do you know that ?

Comment: @GuyFsone It can be interpreted this way. In any case it is not a big problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basically

$$\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\frac{x^n}{(n-k)!}=x^k\sum_{n=k}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n-k}}{(n-k)!}=x^k\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{n}}{n!} = x^ke^x$$

now take $x=\frac12$